# Alter Field Value in View.detail.php ( detail view ) in SUGARCRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm, detailview

I have added a custom field using the below class in my Contact Module. Basically, I have one text field field "project details"  in Contact Module. If user enter some data in project details field in Edit view, then it will be display in Detailed view. I want to alter the value of "project details" field in the detailed view. I want to apply str_replace() function to "project_details" field in that particular detail view only( not in other views ) .  So i think i can use the following class to do that. If there is any alternative also i'm ready to go with it.

FILE PATH : custom/modules/Contacts/views/view.detail.php

```
  class CustomContactsViewDetail extends ContactsViewDetail {

    public function display()
    {
        $someVariable = 'something that generates out field output will go here';

        // Assign custom "Status" value to Smarty template
        $this->ss->assign('STATUS', $somaeVariable);

        parent::display();
    }
}
```

I think, i have to add some code like to this alter or replace some string in the field value. like following sample code. But i know this wont work.

```
 <?php
       require_once('modules/Contacts/views/view.detail.php');

      class CustomContactsViewDetail extends ContactsViewDetail {

        public function display()
        {

        $this->field['project_details']['value'] = str_replace("###EMAIL###", "admin@mywebsite.com", $this->field['project_details']['value']);

            parent::display();
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$this->ev->fieldDefs['project_details']
```